# Increament a variable inside a setInterval if statement and display that variable

Tags: jquery, html

How can I display a variable that is inside a setInterval if statement and it increment at a certain point

**Here is my jquery code**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
           var var1 = setInterval(function(){
               var1 += 1;
               if(var1 == 10){
                   var1 = 0;
                   var var2 = 0;
                   var2++;//->I want it to keep on increamenting
                   var $display = $("p");
                   $display.text(var2);//->this will display the incrementation
               }
           }, 50);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Here is my html code*

```
<html>
    <body>
      <p>0</p>
      <button>Display the if variable</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone who knows or know a example that is exactly similar please comment it here :( appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the declaration an initialization of var2 right before the call to setInterval. This way it will not be reset to zero in each iteration.

Comment: Ohh!! I see it works :D and it sucks how simple the problem was xD and spend almost an hour thinking what on the world is happening to my code :D thank you for the help :D

Comment: btw how to make it stop?

Answer (score 2):

Doing `var var2 = 0;` inside the function resets the value each time, which is not the right thing to do if you want to retain the value. It is better to define it as a [**global variable**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx).

```js
var varTimer;
var var2 = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#start").click(function() {
    var var1 = 0;
    varTimer = setInterval(function() {
      var1 += 1;
      if (var1 == 10) {
        var1 = 0;
        var2++; //->I want it to keep on increamenting
        var $display = $("p");
        $display.text(var2); //->this will display the incrementation
      }
    }, 50);
  });
  $("#stop").click(function() {
    clearInterval(varTimer);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>0</p>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: btw how to make it stop?

Comment: @Middle-Level I updated my answer, I created a new variable `varTimer` for the `setInterval`, you can use `clearInterval(varTimer);` to stop it.